# On tensor product of two complex vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra

Does there exist  two nontrivial  complex vector spaces $V$ and $W$ such that $V \otimes_{\mathbb C} W = {0}$ ?

We know that in this situation  the tensor products of basis elements of $V$ and $W$ should be Zero. But I don't see how does that lead to a contradiction.

Can someone give me a reference regarding  this phenomenon?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: $\dim(V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W)=(\dim V)(\dim W)$ or more precisely, if $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis of $V$, $(w_j)_{j\in J}$ a basis of $W$ then $(v_i\otimes w_j)_{(i,j)\in I\times J}$ is a basis of $V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} W$. So the tensor product of basis elements cannot be $0$.

Comment: @Roland, Yes I also thought along the same line. But what is the justification for the fact that for nonzer $v_i, w_j$ we have the tensor product $v_i \otimes w_j$ is nonzero.

Comment: We shall show that if $v,w$ are non zero, then $v\otimes w\neq 0$. There exist a linear form $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(v)\neq 0$ (use the existence of complements). Similarly, there exist $\psi$ such that $\psi(w)\neq 0$. Then consider the bilinear form $(x,y)\mapsto \varphi(x)\psi(y)$. By universal property, it induces $\Phi:V\otimes W\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\Phi(v\otimes w)=\phi(v)\psi(w)\neq 0$ so $v\otimes w\neq 0$.

Comment: @HARRY what exactly is your definition of a tensor product?  Are you familiar with the "universal property" definition? If so, does Roland's proof make sense?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I think Roland has also used the universal property definition.

Comment: @HARRY Yes, that's what I'm saying. I'm asking whether this is a definition that you are familiar with and whether you understand the proof given

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Though I have not rigorously written down the proof but I think I have understand the proof. I hope that that such $\phi$ and $\psi$ really exists.

Comment: @HARRY For finite dimensional spaces, it's easy to show that such $\phi,\psi$ exist.  For more general spaces, such $\phi,\psi$ are guaranteed to exist by the axiom of choice. I do not know if it holds under some assumption weaker than the axiom of choice.